# How to edit Post Reply on Post View without doing that in a separate View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm creating a Forum. It's an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app.

In the post index view there is a post title and content at the top, and post replies are listed below with a foreach loop. I would like to implement EDIT functions on the same view, without having to create new separate views.

I've already built EDIT function for the post. When a user clicks EDIT button on the post, an `EditPostModal` pops up and it works like a charm. That was quite an easy task for me, since one post view has only one corresponding post.

Now I would like to do something similar for each reply. The problem that I have now is, if I put the new modal window for editing replies in the same foreach loop that I use for displaying replies I will be able to access all the relevant properties for filling in modal info, but that makes a mess. First, I think that it's a bit inappropriate to have one modal for each reply. Also, now every modal is practically the same modal but with different info (different hidden ID and content),  and when I click the submit button, the null exception for `@reply.Id` occurs, I'm assuming because it tries to pass the info from all modals at once to the controller at it's confused.

On the other hand, when I put that modal window outside of foreach loop, I'm unable to access post reply information via model. Or I simply don't know how to achieve that.

Please find the code below (simplified, just the relevant parts).

View models:

```
public class PostIndexModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PostReplyModel> Replies { get; set; }
}

public class PostReplyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string ReplyContent { get; set; }
}
```

Post view Index.cshtml:

```
@model WebProjectAircraftForum.Models.Post.PostIndexModel

<div class="container">
<div class="row PostIndex-PostContent">

    <div class="PostContent-Container">
        <div class="PostContent-Header">
            @Model.CreatedOn
        </div>

        <div class="PostContent-Text">
            @Html.Raw(Model.PostContent)
        </div>

        <div class="PostContent-Footer">
            @if (User.Identity.Name == Model.AuthorName || User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <a class="ClassicButton Button-EditPost" data-target="#modalEditPost" onclick="toggleModalPost()">
                    Edit
                </a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

foreach (var reply in Model.Replies)
{
    <div class="row PostIndex-ReplyContent">
        <div ReplyContent-Container">
            <div class="PostContent-Header">
                @reply.CreatedOn
            </div>

            <div class="PostContent-Text">
                @Html.Raw(reply.ReplyContent)
            </div>

            <div class="PostContent-Footer">
                @if (User.Identity.Name == Model.AuthorName || User.IsInRole("Admin")) //added
                {
                    <a class="ClassicButton Button-EditPost" data-target="#modalEditPost" onclick="toggleModalPostReply()">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    //modal for edit PostReply
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalEditPostReply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEditPostReply" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="EditPostFormHeader">
                    Edit Post Reply
                </div>

                <form id="EditPostForm1" class="EditPostForm" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="EditReply" method="post">
                    <input asp-for="@reply.Id" type="hidden" />

                    <div class="EditPostTextarea">
                        <textarea rows="10" asp-for="@reply.ReplyContent" required></textarea>
                        <label asp-for="@reply.ReplyContent"></label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@reply.ReplyContent" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="CreatePostButtonRow">
                        <input type="submit" value="edit reply" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `PostController` part responsible for accepting this:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditReply(PostReplyModel model)
{
        var reply = _postService.GetReplyById(model.Id);

        await _postService.EditPostReplyContent(reply.Id, model.ReplyContent);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.PostId });
}
```

Could you please assist? Any way to put the modal out of the loop and still be able to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for editing my question. It helped me to understand how to do it better next time.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Oggie, two ways have been shared in my answer below. Please check my detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First way by using loop

View (Index.cshtml):

1.You do not share what is `toggleModalPost` and `toggleModalPostReply` js function. Actually no need use any js function to make modal pop up. Just use default bootstrap attribute `data-toggle="modal"`.

2.Your modal id is `modalEditPostReply` but the value of `data-target` in the anchor does not match it. Besides all the modal should own unique id. You need add an index to make it unique.

```
@model PostIndexModel

@{ int i = 0;}   <!--add here -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row PostIndex-PostContent">   
        <div class="PostContent-Container">
            <div class="PostContent-Header">
                @Model.CreatedOn
            </div>
            <div class="PostContent-Text">
                @Html.Raw(Model.PostContent)
            </div>   
            <div class="PostContent-Footer">       <!--Not sure which modal does this edit button launch-->
                <a class="ClassicButton Button-EditPost" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modalEditPost_@i">
                    EditPost
                </a>             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var reply in Model.Replies)
    {
    <div class="row PostIndex-ReplyContent">
        <div ReplyContent-Container">
            <div class="PostContent-Header">
                @reply.CreatedOn
            </div> 
            <div class="PostContent-Text">
                @Html.Raw(reply.ReplyContent)
            </div>

            <div class="PostContent-Footer">      <!--add data-toggle and change data-target -->   
                <a class="ClassicButton Button-EditPost" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditPostReply_@i" >
                    EditReply
                </a>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
        //modal for edit PostReply
                              //modify the id....
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalEditPostReply_@i" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEditPostReply" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="EditPostFormHeader">
                    Edit Post Reply
                </div>
                <form id="EditPostForm1" class="EditPostForm" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="EditReply" method="post">
                    <input asp-for="@reply.Id" type="hidden" />

                    <div class="EditPostTextarea">
                        <textarea rows="10" asp-for="@reply.ReplyContent" required></textarea>
                        <label asp-for="@reply.ReplyContent"></label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@reply.ReplyContent" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="CreatePostButtonRow">
                        <input type="submit" value="edit reply" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        i++;   //add here...
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

Your frontend uses `asp-for="@reply.PropertyName"`, it will generate `name="reply.PropertyName"`, you need specific the prefix.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditReply([Bind(Prefix ="reply")]PostReplyModel model)
{           
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

---

### The second way by avoid looping

**You can use partial view to reuse the modal.**

View (Index.cshtml):

Now you can use js function to call ajax to load the partial view which can avoid looping the modal.

```
@model PostIndexModel    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row PostIndex-PostContent">   
        <div class="PostContent-Container">
            <div class="PostContent-Header">
                @Model.CreatedOn
            </div>
            <div class="PostContent-Text">
                @Html.Raw(Model.PostContent)
            </div>    
            <div class="PostContent-Footer">
                <a class="ClassicButton Button-EditPost" data-target="#modalEditPost">
                    EditPost
                </a>                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var reply in Model.Replies)
    {
    <div class="row PostIndex-ReplyContent">
        <div ReplyContent-Container">
            <div class="PostContent-Header">
                @reply.CreatedOn
            </div>    
            <div class="PostContent-Text">
                @Html.Raw(reply.ReplyContent)
            </div> 
            <div class="PostContent-Footer">             
                <a class="ClassicButton Button-EditPost" data-target="#modalEditPostReply" 
                                               onclick="toggleModalPostReply('@reply.Id')">   
                    EditReply
                </a>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loadModal">
              <!--load the modal-->
    </div>
    }
</div>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    function toggleModalPostReply(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/Post/LoadPartial?id="+id,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadModal").html(data);
                $('#modalEditPostReply').modal('show')

            }
        })
    }
</script>
}
```

Partial View (_Partial.cshtml locates in Views/Shared folder):

```
@model PostReplyModel
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditPostReply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEditPostReply" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="EditPostFormHeader">
                Edit Post Reply
            </div>
            <form id="EditPostForm1" class="EditPostForm" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="EditReply" method="post">
                <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />

                <div class="EditPostTextarea">
                    <textarea rows="10" asp-for="ReplyContent" required></textarea>
                    <label asp-for="ReplyContent"></label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ReplyContent" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="CreatePostButtonRow">
                    <input type="submit" value="edit reply" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult LoadPartial(int id)
{
    var data = _context.Replies.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return PartialView("_Partial", data);
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditReply(PostReplyModel model)
{           
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rena. I was trying to do it the second way but I was having issues  the partial view.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: You may have misunderstood me. My bad, it's because the way I responded. You did help me and I managed to do it. I was having issues while I was trying to do it myself before you submitted the answer. I was stuck with calling the partial view using `@Html.Action()` and realized it's not available anymore in .net core. Your way with using js and ajax did the job. Tnx again.

Comment: Fine. Glad to help you. :)