# How to pass a value from foreach loop in the view to the controller in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a table in my view that its rows are filled by a foreach loop. A part of this table is as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PmModel)
{
   <td>@Html.DisplayName(item.pmNumber.ToString())</td>
   <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-table btn-modal">Upload</button>
   </td>
}
```

I have a button in each rows and by pressing each of them, a modal form is appeared to upload a file. I use the following code to upload the file and fill database columns based on the file information. But I need to take **pmId** from view to the following action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    var newFileName = string.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), fileExtension);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/PmFiles/UploadedByUsers", newFileName);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }
                    var fileElements = new Models.FileRepository()
                    {
                        fileId = 0,
                        fileName = newFileName,
                        isDownloaded = false,
                        pm = _pmRepository.GetPmById(int Id), //I need to get Id from view
                        uploadDate = DateTime.Now,
                    };
                    _fileRepository.InsertFile(fileElements);
                    _fileRepository.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("PmPage");
        }
```

I use Bootstrap modal:

```
@section Modal{
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
     dir="ltr">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Page" asp-action="UploadFile">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">File Upload</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-mdb-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row mt-2" dir="rtl">
                        <label class="form-label" for="customFile">Select your file:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="customFile" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-mdb-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

In view, I can find pmId using `item.pmNumber` but I don't know how I can take its value to my controller. Please help me.

Update: This script triggers the modal by pressing the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-modal').click(function () {
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can pass the id from the view as part of the post request and get it `public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, int Id)` You could also create class a that wraps the `IFormFile` and the `Id` as properties.

Comment: You have to show your javascript and modal view  where you call upload action

Comment: Thanks, and where is the code you are opening this modal?

Comment: @Serge I corrected the button class in the main question. Please have a look. I have used MDBootstrap

Comment: @Jeffery Can you please show me the process by code?

Comment: @Fardin You need some javascript code to do what you want . Do you have any already, or you use just MDBoostrap package?

Comment: @Serge I just use MDBootstrap. Is it possible through JQuery? How?

Comment: If you check MDBootstrap samples, you will find with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hidden input in your modal and put the modal body in the foreach section to pass the `item.pmNumber` to hidden input.

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class FileModel
{
    public List<PmModel> PmModel { get; set; }
}
public class PmModel
{
    public int pmNumber { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model FileModel
@{ 
    int i = 0;   //add this....
}
@foreach (var item in Model.PmModel)
{
    <td>@Html.DisplayName(item.pmNumber.ToString())</td>
    <td>                                            //change here....
        <button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_@i" class="btn btn-info btn-table btn-modal">Upload</button>
    </td>                       //change here.....
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_@i" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
         dir="ltr">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Page" asp-action="UploadFile">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">File Upload</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-mdb-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row mt-2" dir="rtl">
                              <!--add this-->
                            <input hidden name="id" value="@item.pmNumber" />  
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-2" dir="rtl">
                            <label class="form-label" for="customFile">Select your file:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="customFile" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-mdb-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    i++;            //add here.........
}


@section Scripts {
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PageController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file,int id)
    {
        //do your stuff...
        return View();
    }
}
```

Besides, you can also create a partial view for modal(This partial view still needs a hidden input) to avoid looping modal body code. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70254216/11398810)

Comment: I tried to use this solution but it did not work. You forget to mention the script part related to the modal. I think the modal script at bottom of the body is loaded before the loop. So we cannot match the IDs

Comment: Hi @Fardin, for this solution, no need use any jquery to pass the id. It can get id from foreach loop. any way please share your code.

Comment: Hi @Fardin, you can see that I put the modal code to foreach loop, and in the modal code I add an hidden input and set the value by using `value="@item.pmNumber"`. Each time I trigger the modal it will display the modal with different id. And form submit will dynamically post the id and file.

Comment: Please check the update in the main question. We need to change #exampleModal for each row. So, #exampleModal_@i does not match.

Comment: Hi @Fardin, actually I think you may not read my answer carefully. Did you see I put the modal inside the loop? And for modal popup, you can add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal_@i"` to the button to automatically make it work instead of using jquery.  This is the default bootstrap modal usage.

Comment: @ Rena, Thanks. I need to remove jQuery part and test your solution. I'll tell you the result later. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fardin , ok fine.  Also remember add the index `@{ int i = 0; }` outside the foreach loop and add `i++;` inside the loop. More details you can check my answer.

Comment: An another question. Can we use this approach if we use jquery datatable?

Comment: Maybe not. You know the datatable no need use foreach loop in html so it cannot add index to specify the modal.  Use datatable with bootstrap modal, I did it before, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60276632/11398810) as a reference.

Comment: Your answer solve my problem. Thanks.